# Profile a Single File in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, profile

I create a Web Application project in Netbeans and i have class with `main` function. Now i want to profile this **main function** but when i run profiler, it tries to deploy my project and start tomcat. but i don't want to run tomcat.

Is there any way to profile a single class in Netbeans?

one way to do that is to call that main function from `jsp` file and request that `jsp` file in browser after running web application. but i cant do it because my tomcat is broken

Comment: Making a Java Application project and a common library project would seem beneficial, for bringing structure in the web app too.

Comment: Yes. I understand that Web Application project is not suitable for library but some problems made me to create Web Application.